# Searching in a List, for a string; C#

Tags: c#, string, list, search

I am trying to search a List of strings. I want to be able to return any found results that include information from a string. For example:

(I already have a list with values)
List `strings` contains

> "dog",
>   "cat",
>   "doghouse",
>   "doge",
>   "mouse"

I want a way to check a string, for example:

```
string dog = "dog"
```

And return the values:

> "dog",
>   "doghouse",
>    "doge"

This is what I have so far, at least the portion I need help on.

Console.WriteLine("What would you like to search for (Title: Full Title; Author: first, last): ");

```
                search = Console.ReadLine();

                var results = bookList.Where(x => x.Contains(search)).ToList();

                if (results != null)

                {

                    Console.WriteLine(results);

                    //i--;

                    search = String.Empty;

                    clearvars results;

                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");

                    Console.ReadLine();

                    continue;

                }
```

Comment: What have you tried already? SO is not the place to have your job done for you, but to assist.

Comment: Have a look at LINQ and take it from there

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following.

```
var dog = "dog";
var result = YourList.FindAll(y => y.ToLower().Contains(dog.ToLower()));
```

Comment: List<string> Item = new List<string> { "dog", "cat", "doghouse", "doge", "mouse", "DsdSfSf", "dFdfRSdfS" };
            string FindVeriable="Dog";
            var ValueResult = Item.FindAll(y => y.ToLower().Contains(FindVeriable.ToLower()));

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var results = my list.Where(x => x.Contains(str)).ToList();
```

Comment: I think the Contains method also had a parameter for a case insensitive check